# how to use simple quote with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
chekBDt_001 = {'000123','321556','653982',321456'}
for k = 1:numel(chekBDt_001)
bdd = '"SELECT Value From controlBase WHERE Field=''' chekBDt_001(ii)''' " ';
end
```

I have a problem with `chekBDt_001` by using simple quote, any help?

Comment: I believe you have a typo: `321456'` => `'321456'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your strings into a vector using `[]` and a space between each substring:

```
bdd = ['"SELECT Value From controlBase WHERE Field=''' chekBDt_001(ii) ''' " '];
```